# Find sum of values of points in 2D plane

Tags: data-structures

Given $N$ points in 2D plane, and each point has some value. Have to answer $Q$ queries of the form:

Given $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$, find sum of values of all points $(x,y)$ such that $x_1 \le x \le x_2$ and $y_1 \le y \le y_2$. $N$ and $Q$ are $\le 10^6$. Also it will be helpful if someone can provide implementation.

Comment: This seems like a standard question in computational geometry. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? Note also that we are *not* going to provide any implementation. This is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it in sublinear time.

Comment: Try to use [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a similar data structure.

Comment: How, can you provide any useful link?

Comment: You can find information on k-d trees and their applications to *range search* (which is your problem) on the web and in textbooks on computational geometry. I already gave you one link, namely Wikipedia.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/76527/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44438748/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions, if you're satisfied with fully offline solutions (all points and queries are known beforehand):

1. If coordinates are small enough (e.g. they're integers between $0$ and $C$), you can precalculate summed area table. Precalculate in $O(C^2)$ and answer each query online in $O(1)$. Memory consumption would be $O(C^2)$.
2. If they are not, you can use 2D segment tree with coordinate compression. Build the tree in $O(n \log n)$ (where $n$ is the number of points) and answer single query in $O(\log^2 n)$. Memory consumption would be $O(n \log n)$.
3. The previous solution can be further optimized by adding some precalculations which will exploit the static nature of the tree so that single query becomes $O(\log n)$.
4. You can use sweep line algorithm and a 1D segment tree to answer all queries in $O((n + m) log (n + m))$. This solution is probably the simplest to implement after summed area table.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do 4th?

Comment: @nequit Looks like it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427549/answer-sum-of-elements-in-a-rectangle-query-for-big-grid)

Comment: @nequit You have to put some effort yourself. We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: Sorry I read that wrong, should sleep now. Thanks yeputons.